# Autofixture AutoData error - No arguments were provided

Tags: .net, nunit, moq, autofixture

I'm trying to use the AutoData feature in AutoFixture for my NUnit tests in the following way:

```
[Test]
[AutoData]
public void PharmaciesAndDelegatesShouldBeLinkedEachOther(string s) {
    ...
}
```

However, I'm receiving the following error when running the test. Everything else in the test work correctly as long as I don't pass that parameter:

> Result Message:    No arguments were provided.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you encounter this behavior after installing and using AutoFixture.NUnit2 via NuGet?

Comment: Yes, I installed AutoFixture.Nunit2 via Nuget, version 3.21.1

Comment: How do you run the above test? (e.g. using [TestDriven.Net](http://testdriven.net/) add-in, ReSharper, etc.)

Comment: I'm using the Visual Studio 2013 Test Runner, with the NUnit Test Adapter package. I will give a try TestDriven.Net to see if there it works properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird enough, it seems that the NUnitTestAdapter package is not compatible with Autofixture AutoData attribute... I installed TestDriven.Net and ran the tests with it and AutoData works perfectly, feeding the parameters to the method with no problem.

Thanks for all your answers!

Answer (score 8):

Make sure that you have installed the latest version of *NUnit (2.6.3)* NuGet package in your tests project. If you are using the native NUnit runner (console or GUI), also make sure that you are using the latest version of it (2.6.3)

Then, If you have *AutoFixture.Nunit2* package installed in your tests project, and you use the latest NUnit 2.6.3 and Resharper version at least 8.1, you need to manually add binding redirect to *app.config* file of your tests project (as was stated in the *readme.txt* file what was opened after *AutoFixture.Nunit2* package installation):

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="nunit.core.interfaces" publicKeyToken="96d09a1eb7f44a77" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.3.13283" newVersion="2.6.3.13283" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

If you don't have *app.config* file in you tests project, please add one, and paste the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="nunit.core.interfaces" publicKeyToken="96d09a1eb7f44a77" culture="neutral" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.3.13283" newVersion="2.6.3.13283" />
      </dependentAssembly> 
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Aferward, check if you have added the following class in your tests project ( Should be added during installation of *AutoFixture.Nunit2* package as *LocalAddin.cs* file )

```
using NUnit.Core.Extensibility;

namespace Test.Project
{
    [NUnitAddin]
    public class LocalAddin : Ploeh.AutoFixture.NUnit2.Addins.Addin
    {   
    }
}
```

That's all. I'm using VS2013, NUnit 2.6.3, AutoFixture.Nunit2 3.21.1, Resharper tests runner and native NUnit runners (console and GUI), and it works great.